# How to repair Colors problem in Chrome

Tags: debian, colors, chrome, display

Black colors and shadows in videos on Google Chrome have a problem, I don't know how to phrase this problem in words properly so watch these screenshots from the same video on same pixels (360p)
using Google Chrome :
[image: check the eyes and shadows]

using Firefox :
[image]

my laptop graphics :

```
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5 M 520 (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 9576
           clock speeds: max: 2400 MHz 1: 1333 MHz 2: 1599 MHz 3: 1199 MHz 4: 1333 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.org 1.19.2 driver: intel tty size: 168x47 Advanced Data: N/A for root
```

uname :

```
Linux www 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u5 (2017-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "DRI" "3" 
EndSection
```

**Update**: now I use DRI3 version but the problem didn't change

**Update 2**: more recognizable example :

Chrome :
[image]

Firefox :
[image]

**Update 3**: The problem doesn't occur while using `Fedora 25` live USB

Comment: Have you tried using `chromium` ?

Comment: Yea , and it's the same

Comment: Try live booting some other OS. eg `Antergos` or `Fedora`

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal the problem doesn't occur while using `Fedora 25` live USB

Comment: Now, its clear the problem is in graphics driver. Switch to Fedora now. Debian has lots of compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about the reason but switching from GNOME to KDE Plasma fixed it very well and also fixed some minor lags.